# Any way to take SCSS code compiled through SASS Bourbon and decompile it into a readable format?

Tags: css, sass, bourbon

I've got SCSS code that is all on one line as a result of being compiled through SASS Bourbon. As a result it's basically unreadable.

I'm just wondering if there is a program out there that can take the SCSS code and break it up into a more readable CSS format?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Bourbon does not compile Sass. Depending on how you are compiling your Sass (command line, Rails, grunt, etc) you might need to pass a `--style expanded` argument so that the output is not compressed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try pasting the SCSS into [SassMeister](http://sassmeister.com/) and have it transpiled into CSS. The result is regular uncompressed CSS, so you should have no problems reading it.